# 10.04 upgrade (to 12...) never works

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 10.04

When I attempt to upgrade from 10.04 to 12..., I 
get the following message(s) at the point of 'setting up files': (YadYada = www.):

```
W:Failed to fetch YadaYada us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/intrepid-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
, W:Failed to fetch YadaYada us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/intrepid-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
, W:Failed to fetch  //us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/intrepid-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
, W:Failed to fetch  //us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/intrepid-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Suggestions would be appreciated, as the Chromium (and fails with adobe Flash) are becoming frequent.

Thanking you in advance,

Tatter

(P.S.; as this site chokes on more than two links mentioned in this post; hence: YadaYada).

Comment: What's the output of: cat /etc/issue

Comment: root@janis-desktop:/home/janis# 
root@janis-desktop:/home/janis# cat/etc/issues
bash: cat/etc/issues: No such file or directory
root@janis-desktop:/home/janis# cat /etc/issues
cat: /etc/issues: No such file or directory
root@janis-desktop:/home/janis# cat/etc/issue
bash: cat/etc/issue: No such file or directory
root@janis-desktop:/home/janis# cat: etc/issues
No command 'cat:' found, did you mean:
 Command 'cat' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'catg' from package 'nauty' (multiverse)
cat:: command not found